# MYSQL SQL syntax error on Wordpress Posts page

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I see the following error on my Wordpress Posts page when I enable debugging.  I only noticed this when I started adding categories to my posts and they were not saving.  I never used categories before, so I am not sure how long this issue has existed.  I have switched the theme and disabled all plugins and still see the issue.

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY t.name ASC' at line 1]

```
SELECT t.*, tt.*, tr.object_id FROM wp_terms AS t 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt 
ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr 
ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id 
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category', 'post_tag', 'post_format', 'yst_prominent_words') 
AND tr.object_id IN (1461, 1475, 1539, 1605, 1708, 1732, 1760, 1764, 2292, 2311, 2343, 2368, 2374, 2380) 
AND t.term_id NOT IN() ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

Comment: please remember to indent your code!

Comment: Can you add the wordpress code that constructs this query?

Comment: My best guess is that it is happening here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php  Line 457 is where the invalid line is being added.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression is not valid:

```
AND t.term_id NOT IN()
```

Comment: Yes that is the syntax error, but I don't know why Wordpress is constructing an SQL query with a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add values to the last `NOT IN()` statement.

Comment: Yes that is the syntax error, but I don't know why Wordpress is constructing an SQL query with a syntax error